# URL on call end in studio?

Tags: twilio-studio

In Studio, is there a way to have it call a URL when the call is completed? When it's not Studio, I just use a "StatusCallback" URL with "StatusCallbackEvent" set to completed. But the docs for Studio warn to leave the "CALL STATUS CHANGES" for the phone number set to the studio flow, otherwise I end up with "stuck" executions that I have to manually kill. Anywhere that I'm forcing the call to end I could put in a http request first before ending, but if someone just hangs up in my IVR, I want to get notified of it so that I can input the ending timestamp and call cost in my tracking system.

I thought about setting the call status changes pointing to my page and having my page end the execution, but it appears that there is not actually a REST API to stop an active execution. The “stuck executions” article says to either use Console to “stop execution”, or to use the REST API to delete the execution. But those are FAR from the same thing. The REST API totally deletes the execution from even appearing in the logs, not just ends its runtime. That would not be acceptable.

Worst-case, I'll run a daily post-process which grabs the call end data from all calls made that day, but it's a bit ugly compared to how my (non-studio) programs do it with the StatusCallback.